# Why GEE and GLM estimate the different standard errors？

Tags: generalized-linear-model, standard-error, generalized-estimating-equations

I use the independence working correlation， the parameter estimates β in glm and GEE is identical，but the standard errors is different。
The standard error of both GEE and GLM are calculated using the Fisher information matrix.
GEE and GLM use same score function, so they have the same fisher information matrix, but have the difference standard error,why?

---

```
a = rbinom(10,1,0.6)
b = rbinom(10,1,0.4)
id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4)
summary(glm(a~b,family=binomial(link="logit")))

Call:
glm(formula = a ~ b, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

Deviance Residuals: 
Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.4006  -1.3448   0.9695   0.9695   1.1774  

Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   0.5108     0.7303   0.699    0.484
b            -0.5108     1.5916  -0.321    0.748

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 13.460  on 9  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 13.358  on 8  degrees of freedom
AIC: 17.358

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

summary(gee(a~b,family=binomial(link="logit"),id=id,corstr = 
"independence"))
Beginning Cgee S-function, @(#) geeformula.q 4.13 98/01/27
running glm to get initial regression estimate
(Intercept)           b 
  0.5108256  -0.5108256 

 GEE:  GENERALIZED LINEAR MODELS FOR DEPENDENT DATA
 gee S-function, version 4.13 modified 98/01/27 (1998) 

Model:
 Link:                      Logit 
 Variance to Mean Relation: Binomial 
 Correlation Structure:     Independent 

Call:
gee(formula = a ~ b, id = id, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    corstr = "independence")

Summary of Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.62500 -0.59375  0.37500  0.37500  0.50000 


Coefficients:
              Estimate Naive S.E.    Naive z Robust S.E.   Robust z
(Intercept)  0.5108256  0.8164966  0.6256311   0.8055364  0.6341434
b           -0.5108256  1.7795130 -0.2870592   0.9568467 -0.5338636

Estimated Scale Parameter:  1.25
Number of Iterations:  1

Working Correlation
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1
```

Comment: If you paste the code in as text, people can copy it and rerun it. It makes it easier for them.

Comment: You have id in the gee call, but not the glm. And your sample size is small. Remove the id from the gee, and increase the sample size, you get almost identical results.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and I've posted the code in the comments below. I am writing a paper, and I need to use GEE under small sample, but GEE and GLM get different results under independent model, which bothers me very much. I need to know why it is so, so that I can give a reasonable explanation to my advisor.

Comment: When I use the independence working correlation, whether there is id or not, it does not affect the parameter estimation and standard error estimation of GEE。

Comment: Here's an Rstudio project with a larger sample where they are the same: https://rstudio.cloud/content/4320416

Comment: I clicked on your link, but I didn't find the R project in it. Could you be more specific, please。

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Click File, Open, glm_vs_gee.R.